# Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring

@PostMapping
    public UserResponse createUser(@RequestBody UserRequest userDetail) {

```
    UserResponse returnValue = new UserResponse();
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetail, userDto);

    UserDto storedData = userService.createUser(userDto);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(storedData, returnValue);

    return returnValue;
}
```

this is the code I am getting this error

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-05-13T12:24:04.866+0000",
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
"path": "/users"
```

}

I have tried a lot of different ways still not getting the solution
This is the image from the postman
[image from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZhyb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Postman to fire the request? you might want to check these settings

[image]

### Edit. Add another image for troubleshooting

[image]

Comment: but still getting the same result

Comment: can you show me a screenshot of how you're creating your request?

Comment: I have added the image a bove

Comment: What does that yellow triangle beside the dropdown 'JSON' says?

Comment: The message says: "The language selected is different from the language inferred from content_type header"

Comment: check my edited answer. Is your header correctly set to `application/json`?

Comment: @khalidhussien you're most welcome. Please accept my answer if you don't mind =]

Answer (score -1):

That because your service is only accepting application/json content type. If you want to accepting application/x-www-form-urlencoded you can add consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE inside @PostMapping annotation

bellow is sample of service that accept application/json and give application/json response.

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/v1/agent/create", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ApiResponseWrapperDto createAgent(@RequestBody ApiRequestWrapperDto request) throws Exception {
        return this.agentManagementApiHandler.createAgent(request);
}
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: the problem still the same